# Draggable div and padding

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've implemented an AngularJS directive to make elements draggable and after that, I applied it to a *div* element that I want to use as floating menu for my website.

The problem that I've got appears when I drag a *draggable div* that have been placed into an element that has specific padding values, also, it shows up when the *draggable div* have set margin attributes. Depending on those attribute values, **on mouse move, my *draggable div* jumps from the original position to some offset** and I don't want it to happen.

I created an example to demonstrate this issue, you can see the link below.
And here is my question: How can I make the movement of my *draggable divs* smooth, **without removing padding/margin attributes**?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwiDo9gx5nAcz4Z0daTo?p=preview

```
<body style="padding-top:20%">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" style="background-color:black;color:white;z-index:2;" ng-draggable="vm.dragOptions">

        <span class="col-xs-12 modal-header divheader" style="cursor:pointer">
            List of objects
        </span>
        <div style="margin:0px;" class="padding">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

UPD

The next snippet provided by @user6028084 helped to solve the issue in the plnkr, but in an actual app it screws up my css styles, so, anyone who comes with another solution is very welcome.

```
.ng-isolate-scope{
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Might help... Add `position:relative` to body and add `position:absolute` to .ng-isolate-scope

Comment: @user6028084, it helped in the plnkr shown, but in my real app it doesn't, it screws the design up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `padding-top:20%` it works as you pointed out.
So if you want to keep that then you must compensate by that amount.

It works perfectly on my browser if I add the corresponding amount (117 px in my case) to the script

Changing the line 56 in your script to the following makes it work no matter what resolution the browser is at - full screen or minimal:

```
startY = e.clientY - elem[0].offsetTop +117;
```

Edit: alternatively just remove the offset altogether

```
startY = e.clientY;
```

Edit2:
I have changed the way it was getting it's coordinates. The values for startX and startY were incorrect originally as was the assignment of x and y in the mousemove event.

This is the edited plunker for a full working version:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdHd90ZSDer1ao6njUuf?p=preview)

Comment: This won't do, I don't want to modify the directive whenever I want to use it in various places.

Comment: @MovsarBekaev : in that case can't you just remove the elem[0].offsetTop to make it 
startY = e.clientY ;
This will still work without the jump. (edited the post to show)

Comment: then it won't move by Y altogether, can you try to fix this in the plnkr that I provided?

Comment: @MovsarBekaev - full working version now in the above

Comment: yes, I removed both of the offsetTop's and now it works perfectly,  I don't know why it was there in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: There was one more issue with this, after removing offsets altogether, the box started to jump when it has been moved in the second time - it jumped back to the initial position, so I came with new offsets, and now it truly works))